# Stored Procedure returns null or empty value in php

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I am using sql server 2012 and connected to php. when I executing the stored procedure in sql management studio it works fine. but when i calling stored procedure in php it returns empty or null value

I found the root cause. I use PRINT in that stored procedure. if i remove that print in Stored procedure it works fine in php. if i use means it getting empty value

Why? and how to get result from stored procedure in PHP in this scenario ?(sp have print statement)

Stored Procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spname 
       @Id INT
AS
Begin
    PRINT "some notes"
    SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME
end
```

Php code

```
$sp="EXEC spname @Id=20";
$query=$con->prepare($sp);
$query->execute();
$result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print '<PRE>';
print_r($result);
```

Comment: Add SET NOCOUNT ON; after BEGIN statement and check if it helps you.

Comment: @PareshJ Yes thanks now i got the results. But i don't want to modify the Stored Procedure. How can I handle this on PHP side?

Comment: How you will be able to add SET NOCOUNT in your PHP code? You have to add this in your SP only.

Comment: There is no workaround for this as for as I know other than altering the sp.

Answer (score 2):

Please try this:

```
$sp="SET NOCOUNT ON;EXEC spname @Id=20";
$query=$con->prepare($sp);
$query->execute();
$result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print '<PRE>';
print_r($result);
```